# Unity 4.3 2d mode, how to make an object appear splitted on the screen if moved over the screen border

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sprite

Basically in Unity 4.3 on 2d mode, I need to sometimes have objects (with sprites) that can move over the screen size border (left, right, top and bottom), when they pass the border, they should appear at the opposite like this image explain:

[image]

the first thing I had in mind was to just create a copy of the object at runtime, show it at the opposite side, and when the dragged object is completely out of the screen size, destroy that one and let only the other (new object) live. But probalby this is a bad way to do it, does exist a better way to achieve this result ?

Answer (score 0):

Nope. You got it right. There is no way of the two halves appearing at opposite sides of the screen but being the same thing. Except maybe for some camera trickery but that would be for special effects, not for game logic.

Depending on what type of game you're making this will bring with it some mean problems. For instance the copy might collide with something where the original obviously will not. The trick is to apply all rules and effects from one instance to the other as well.